# Hibernate HQL: pass pair values as parameters in IN clause

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am facing a problem: how to pass parameters to HQL for pair values in query with IN clause like - 
`select id, name from ABC where (id, reg_date) in ('x', 'y')`. And the parameters are of different data types string (id) and reg_date (date). 
Now, in HQL I can write:

```
hql = "select id, Name from ABC where (id, date) in (:listparam1)"
hibernateTemplate.findbynamedparam(hql, "listparam1", values).
```

Problem: how to pass a list of id and date pairs in HQL? Both parameters are of different data types: one is `String` and the other is `Timestamp`. I tried `Map` and concatenation of both values in `Object`, 2 dimensional array, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, a.name from ABC a where a.id || '.' || a.date in (:id_date)
```

....and you need to pass as parameter "id_date" collection of string of concatenated id and name. If performance is an obstacle, you can create function index on your SQL database(s) that do exactly the same job (of course if your database(s) supports function indexes)

Answer (score -1):

You can implement it next way:

```
hql = "select a.id, a.Name from ABC a where a.id in (:listid) or a.date in (:datelist)"
```

or

```
 hql = "select a.id, a.Name from ABC a where a.id in (:listid) and a.date in (:datelist)"
```

regardless of what condition must be satisfied with the result

Comment: Thanks for reply. We can't use 'or' - 'and' condition as it will not give the desired resutls. These conditions will give all data which either has id or date or any combination of id and date which will be incorrect. We need to fetch data only on the base of both pair combination only.

Comment: And there is a other problem of using single IN clause. We need to fetch data for 5000 values. IN clause takes only max 1000 values. To pass more than 1000 values, you can use only pair values. Please let me know if you have any way to customize a list or bean to pass different data types pair values to IN clause.